# Problems to create a dynamic link for one of my menu buttons in a wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

The link is to a page with a booking widget and needs to include the text `?certificate=` and the current users email address. The email address gets passed to the booking widget which then allows the user to book appointments they've already purchased.

I found a suggestion and some code but cannot make it work. The suggestion was to:

> Make a custom menu link in the wordpress admin panel with a # for the
>   Url.

Then the code is suposed to do the rest. Ive tried putting the code in the `header.php` file as well as making it into a plugin but in each case it breaks the website. Here's the code I have so far...

```html
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {    
      var targetNav = $('li.menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-557 a');
   var userEmail = '<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->user_email;?>';
   var userUrl = 'https://www.ourlinguafranca.com/book/' + '?certificate=' + userEmail/;
      targetNav.attr('href',userUrl);
    });
  </script>
<?php }  else { ?>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {    
      var targetNav = $('li.menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-557 a');
      targetNav.attr('href','https://www.ourlinguafranca.com/my-account/');
    });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery instead of $ sign bcoz sometimes $ is not working in wordpress

Comment: Thanks Moshin, ive swaped the $ for jQuery but no luck. I fixed another error too so now the site isnt crashing, but the script isnt running. The link is showing as ourlinguafranca.com/# Where do you think I should add this code?

Comment: Actually its fine, i got it working. I was referencing the "class" in the targetNav variable instead of the "id". When i swapped this it worked. But thanks Moshin for catching the $ issue.